# AndEngine: Density, Elasticity, Friction, Gravity concepts

Tags: physics, andengine

I am new to AndEngine. I have seen some physics examples from AndEngine Example package. I want to know the role of density, elasticity, friction and gravity while implementing physics. How they effect a physical object in andengine? I know its very basic example but I want to start andengine from very basics. Can anybody make these concepts clear to me?

Answer (score 4):

AndEngine uses Box2D. You can find more information simply by seeing the manual, which includes explanations for the concepts you're asking, [here](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972). Specifically, 6.2 :)

For examples, if you feel confortable with javascript, I would suggest you to go [here](http://box2d-javascript-fun.appspot.com/), a website with a lot of working examples of a Javascript port of Box2D (I believe that the names of the classes are the same).

Comment: @fableal, please don't edit my posts with your own words. Instead, add it as a comment. :)